# When doing make (gcc), how can you pull in all required libraries into a specific folder?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, gnu

I am trying to recompile a program compiled for linux, to run under Windows using cygwin.  But there are obviously a lot of libraries that are dependencies.

When I use make/gcc to build, how can I somehow pull in all the dependencies into a folder in linux, and then copy those dependencies over to cygwin and do the make over there?

Thanks

Comment: As per my knowledge, you cannot pull (copy) all dependent libraries using make/gcc. All libraries will be present at /lib or /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib or user defined path with linker option -L. All libraries need to be copied manually for your purpose (yes you may have to take care of preserving symbolic links e.g. libxml.so -> libxml.so.2 -> libxml.so.2.0). To find out the dependencies, 'ldd' is one useful utility for your help.

Comment: How would that help you? You can't use Linux libraries under Windows.